# Looking for elegant way of solving Stream.allMatch equals to true when processing a potentially empty stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to get a **false** value using a single stream chain which ends with allMatch terminal operation.

However, I found out that due to the design of the allMatch operation, it will return true when it processes an empty stream.

For example, the following codes return **true** because the filtered stream is empty down the pipeline.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abc", "efg", "hij");
boolean isAllStartsWith1 = list.stream().filter(s-> s.endsWith("x")).allMatch(s->s.startsWith("1"));
System.out.println(isAllStartsWith1);
```

In order to get my expected result (**false**), I would need to collect the stream into a temporary list and add additional checking to confirm that if it is empty before passing to allMatch operation for the final processing. This makes the whole processes look very clunky, is there any more elegant solution to this problem?

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abc", "efg", "hij");
List<String> filteredList = list.stream().filter(s-> s.endsWith("x")).collect(Collectors.toList());
boolean isAllStartsWith1 = !filteredList.isEmpty() && filteredList.stream().allMatch(s->s.startsWith("1"));
                        
System.out.println(isAllStartsWith1);
```

Comment: There's a bit of ambiguity: what does `isAllStartsWith1` amount to: 1. all `list` elements start with `1`? or 2. All `list` elements ending in `x` also start with `1`? The questions you asked imply the latter, but the variable name `isAllStartsWith1` introduces ambiguity.

Comment: @ernest_k, it is the latter. If you were me, how would you name this variable?

Comment: In your place, I'd probably give it an even less meaningful name :) - I was just trying to be sure your question was understood correctly. I think Rob gives you the right answer then.

Comment: What if the original list is empty? Should this be treated the same as non-empty but only containing elements not starting with `x`?

Comment: @Holger, if the original list is empty, I expect the same output as my second code block in my question.

Comment: Then, `boolean result = list.stream().filter(s -> s.endsWith("x")) .map(s -> s.startsWith("1")) .reduce(Boolean::logicalAnd) .orElse(false);` would work but it’s not short-circuiting.

Comment: @holger, Thank you, I tested your solution in the IDE and I found out that its outputs match the second code block in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can count with `.count()` to return true if the result is greater than 0, false otherwise.

```
System.out.println(list.stream().filter(s -> s.endsWith("x")).count() > 0);
```

Comment: You could drop the `? true: false` part.

Comment: like this?`System.out.println(!list.stream().filter(s -> s.endsWith("x")).allMatch(String::isEmpty));`

Comment: No, exactly as you wrote in your answer, except the `? true: false` part, verbatim. `list.stream()...count() > 0` already *is* a boolean expression, do you don't need the ternary if-else.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your warning.

Comment: This completely ignores the requirement to test whether all elements start with `"1"`